# Multiple audios on one PC Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, multiple-monitors

I am setting up a PC Win 10 for a motor home.
Drivers screen for navigation and cameras.
Back screen for passengers to do what ever, video, audio books check the map, use the cameras, etc.
The back monitor is the main monitor, the front monitor is secondary.

All works good except audio.

Front and rear speakers output the same audio.
Front needs map directions rear needs what ever audio not mixed.

The PC is outputting to a display port (back monitor) and an HDMI (front monitor).
The audio is through the audio jack and an external USB A to D converter.  I looked at the multi-seat options, but I want the maps and cameras to be viewable from the back also (stops the “Are we there yet.” questions).

I looked through the other posts and didn't see anything applicable, if I missed something just point me in the right direction.  TIA

Comment: Are they using different applications?

Comment: The front monitor generally uses only the map (an old copy of Street Atlas , I'm looking for something better) and an audio book player (the only one I currently use is VLC). the back monitor can use any application on the box. When underway there is no internet connection.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Voicemeeter Banana

https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm

Set your two audio sources (applications) to Voicemeeter VAIO and Voicemeeter Aux respectively (these are your two virtual inputs). Then set your two hardware outs to A1 and A2 (top right). Then direct A1 and A2 (in the columns for your virtual inputs) to A1 and A2 in whichever order you like.

Comment: Viocemeeter is a nice piece of software and split up the inputs and outputs perfectly.  The only issue I have now is how to make windows keep Viocemeeter as the default sound device.  Every time a monitor or adapter is turned on or off Windoze reconfigures the default sound device.  I’m not the only one with this issue and I haven't found a way to select the windows default using a batch command.  So Thanks for the help. Onward and Upward.

Comment: You could try disabling all the other sound devices in your audio devices or device manager. Windows should remember they are disabled when they reconnect and not switch to them because they are disabled.

PS: This is supposed to work, but I've heard from many people it often doesn't...